# How to insert Event for specific user's calendar as Salesforce Sites Guest user

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, calendar

I [Salesforce Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_setup_overview.htm) set up on a sandbox org. I'm trying to create an [Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) to be added to a specific user's calendar when a Guest user clicks Save on the public Visualforce page below.

[image]
The page's custom controller:

```
public class MyEventController {
  public MyEventController() {
  }

  public Datetime AppointmentDate { get; set; }

  public Pagereference Save() {
    Event event = new Event(Subject = 'New Event');
    event.Type = 'Meeting';
    event.Location = '123 main st';
    event.StartDateTime = this.AppointmentDate;
    event.EndDateTime = this.AppointmentDate; 
    insert event;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Currently, when the Site Guest User clicks Save, the event shows on the System Administrator's calendar.

How can the event be inserted to another, specific user's calendar?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `OwnerId` to the user you wish to assign it to.